# How to enable python-pylint for the all files by default?

Tags: python, flycheck

I can enable `python-pylint` for a opened Python file doing:

`M-x flycheck-select-checker` and enter `python-pylint`

It think it says `C-c ! s` to enable it on all Python files.(the message hides itself so I couldn't read it).

---

=> Is it possible to do this in `.emacs` for all the Python files by default?

My setup:

```
(require 'flycheck)
(require 'flycheck-mypy)

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode) ;(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "~/venv/bin/pylint")
            (setq flycheck-pylintrc "~/.pylintrc")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following line solved my problem:
`(flycheck-add-next-checker 'python-flake8 'python-pylint)`

> `defun flycheck-add-next-checker` checker next & optional append Set
>   next to run after checker. Both arguments are syntax checker symbols.

link: https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/syntax-checkers.html (on bottom of the page).